# CD Burning Software

Tags: iso, optical-media

What are some good alternatives to Nero for CD/DVD Burning?

At the minimum I'd like to be able to burn data CD/DVD, Audio CD, and burn from ISO images. Preferably, the application will be small, and not take up any resources unless I am running the application.

My target operating systems are Windows Server 2008/SBS2008, Windows 7, & Vista.

Comment: As a note windows 7 burns .ISO files by default

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [CDBurner XP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) usually suffice for casual tasks but it's not that light (it's featherweight near Nero though)
- [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) is tiny; I use it for ISO mounting and ripping, but it can also do regular burns

Answer (score 15):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)

Comment: My only beef with ImgBurn is you have to create an ISO before burning it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

I have used [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) for quite some time and it has always done it's job for me and it does all of the things that you describe. When you're used to Nero, CDBurnerXP will feel a lot lighter.

In short:

- Lightweight? **Yes**.
- Ability to burn data CD/DVD? **Yes**.
- Ability to burn audio CD? **Yes**.
- Ability to burn ISO images? **Yes**.
- Small? The installer is 3.1 MB, so I guess that's a **yes**.
- **No background processes** unless you run the application.
- I had it running on **Vista** and **Windows 7**. Not sure about Windows Server 2008.
- It's **free**.

Answer (score 5):

I use the very lightweight [IsoRecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) for burning ISOs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't go wrong with [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/).  Open source, does just about every version of the CD and DVD specs you can think of, burns images, makes images, etc. For bonus cool points, it even came out of the Google Summer Of Code a few years ago.

True story: IR is the only CD burning program that has never coastered a disc on me.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I like the [NTI](http://www.ntius.com/en/us/home/default.asp) CD burning products.  I use CD & DVD Maker at the moment, which shipped with my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DeepBurner - portable edition](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=products&pr=deepburner&prr=portableed). It's about as straight forward as anything I've used.

Answer (score 0):

One little know product that is not bloated, with lot of features and very good quality is [Ones](http://ww1.tx-software.com/boutique_us/liste_produits.cfm?type=7&code_lg=lg_us)